# Intuition on Minimizing Squared Distance

Tags: calculus, geometry, statistics, intuition, variance

Say that we have a bunch of random-values $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$

Let $\bar{X}$ be the mean of these random-values. The variance of this sample-set is given by:

$$\sum(x_i-\bar{X})^2$$

Apparently, the above sum is smaller than if $\bar{X}$ were any other value besides the average of the $n$ observations.

I've seen a Calculus-based explanation...are there other ways to show this? Perhaps geometrically or algebraically?

Thanks.

---

Comment: If by "bigger" you mean "smaller" and by "maximizing" you mean "minimizing", then yes.

Comment: Lol - thanks @DavidK Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\bar{X}$.

Our goal is to show that for $b\in\mathbb{R}$, the sum
$$\sum (x_i-b)^2$$
is minimized when and only when $b=a$.

**Solution #$1$:**$\;$Using only elementary algebra . . .
\begin{align*}
&\sum(x_i-b)^2-\sum(x_i-a)^2\\[4pt]
=\;&
\left(\sum x_i^2-2b\sum x_i+nb^2\right)
-
\left(\sum x_i^2-2a\sum x_i+na^2\right)
\\[4pt]
=\;&
n(b^2-a^2)-2(b-a)\sum x_i
\\[4pt]
=\;&
n(b^2-a^2)-2(b-a)(na)
\\[4pt]
=\;&
n(b^2-2ab+a^2)
\\[4pt]
=\;&
n(b-a)^2
\\[4pt]
\ge\;&\,0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
with equality if and only if $b=a$.

**Solution #$2$:**$\;$Using vector geometry . . .

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, let 
\begin{align*}
P&=(x_1,...,x_n)\\[4pt]
A&=(a,...,a)\\[4pt]
B&=(b,...,b)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and let $l$ be the line with parametric form
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=t\\
\;\vdots\;\;\;\,\vdots\;\;\vdots\\
x_n=t
\end{cases}
$$
Interpreted geometrically,

- $\sum (x_i-a)^2$ is the square of the distance from $P$ to $A$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\sum (x_i-b)^2$ is the square of the distance from $P$ to $B$.

Note that the point $A$ is on the line $l$, and $B$ is just an arbitrary point on $l$.

Thus, with our geometric interpretation, our goal is to show that $A$ is the unique point on $l$ which is closest to $P$.

It suffices to show $\vec{PA}\perp l$.

Letting $\vec{U}=\langle{1,...,1}\rangle$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\vec{PA}\cdot\vec{U}\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(\vec{A}-\vec{P}\right)\cdot \vec{U}\\[4pt]
=\;&\vec{A}\cdot\vec{U}-\vec{P}\cdot\vec{U}\\[4pt]
=\;&na-\sum x_i\\[4pt]
=\;&0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $\vec{PA}\perp l$, as required.